# How to fade the topviewcontoller while using ECSlidingController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ecslidingviewcontroller

I am using the ECSlidingController in my project. But my project demands the fading of the top view controller while sliding. I too used https://github.com/aryaxt/iOS-Slide-Menu
but in this only the under view controller fades instead i want the top view controller to fade while slid.

Please suggest how to fade the top view controller while using ECsliding controller.

Answer (score 0):

It is all about the transition class you use.
You need to set `alpha` of your `topVC` in the method which you implement your animation of your transition class (e.g. `MEZoomAnimationController` and `animateTransition:`)

For more info on transitions: google ***custom transitions*** or go to http://www.objc.io/issue-5/view-controller-transitions.html